# I m searching for a specific string in multiple ".txt" files using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to search strings like "a.aiq" in multiple .txt files and I want those ".aiq" results to be printed

So far I have written below code. It gives no error but doesn't give me desired result.

```
import glob
import re
import os

src = "C:\Python26\sample"
file_array = glob.glob(os.path.join(src,"*.txt"))

fi = open("aiq_hits.txt","w")

for input_file in file_array:

    fo = open(input_file,"r")
    line= fo.readline()
    for line in fo:
        line=line.strip()
        x= re.findall('\S *.aiq\S*',line)
        line= fo.readline()
        for item in x:
            fi.write("%s\n" % item)
            fo.close()
```

fi.close()

Comment: To improve your question describe the result you got. How is it differ from desired result?

Answer (score 0):

```
str = fo.readline()
while str:     
...   
    str = fo.readline()
```

should be replaced by:

```
for str in fo:
```

The first question is:
Is file_array correct?
Use for example

```
for input_file in file_array:
    print input_file #add parenthesis in python 3
```

Comment: Ok, so you should write the code for processing a single file, and try it. If it doesn't work, post here a short file example.

Comment: btw, why did you use open(, "rb")? Why binary?

Comment: But i m getting the complete line as output instead of specific string i m trying to search

Comment: Can anyone help me out on this